# Python : Passing username password to fetch a url response in json using method GET

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, api, redhat

Scenario: 
I have a python code which gives me exact results in windows 10 OS but when I run the same in REDHAT 6.4 it throws an error.

I am trying to open a API URL and fetch the json content and further manipulate it.

Here is the code:

```
import json
import urllib
url = 'https://@username:password@api.locu.com/v1_0/venue/search'
data = json.load(urllib.urlopen(url)
print data
```

When I run this code in windows10 platform with python version 2.7.13 it gives me exact output, but the same when run in REDHAT 6.4 platform gives an error related to authentication inturn it returns me with no json data.
Can't I use the format below or I need to pass the authentication as headers?

```
https://@username:password@apiurl
```

If I need to pass the authentication as headers how can I do that?

*note: I am using the Redhat OS in a VM.
Not sure if this is proxy issue.

Comment: http deprecated authentication in URLs. they may have changed their API

Comment: But it works well in WINDOWS 10OS the problem only starts when I use it in redhat Vm

Comment: "gives an error related to authentication inturn it returns me with no json data" - please quote the error message in the question